# PJSIP compilation Error for iOS5

Tags: iphone, ios5, pjsip

Please help to compile siphone for iOS 5.

I am trying to compile pjsip for siphone project. 
    PJSIP source - svn co http://svn.pjsip.org/repos/pjproject/trunk pjproject
    Siphone code - svn checkout http://siphon.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ siphon
Following the build-libpj.sh script from code.google.com/p/siphon/downloads/list

Getting the following error:

```
`if test ! -d ../lib; then mkdir -p ../lib; fi`
`echo ranlib -static -o ../lib/libpj-arm-apple-darwin10.a  output/pjlib-arm-apple-darwin10  /ioqueue_select.o  output/pjlib-arm-apple-darwin10/file_access_unistd.o  output/pjlib-arm-apple-darwin10/file_io_ansi.o  output/pjlib-arm-apple-darwin10/os_core_unix.o  output/pjlib-arm-apple-darwin10/os_error_unix.o  output/pjlib-arm-apple-darwin10/os_time_unix.o  output/pjlib-arm-apple-darwin10/os_timestamp_posix.o  output/pjlib-arm-apple-darwin10/os_info_iphone.o  output/pjlib-arm-apple-darwin10/guid_simple.o  output/pjlib-arm-apple-darwin10/os_core_darwin.o  output/pjlib-arm-apple-darwin10/addr_resolv_sock.o  output/pjlib-arm-apple-darwin10/log_writer_stdout.o  output/pjlib-arm-apple-darwin10/os_timestamp_common.o  output/pjlib-arm-apple-darwin10/pool_policy_malloc.o  output/pjlib-arm-apple-darwin10/sock_bsd.o  output/pjlib-arm-apple-darwin10/sock_select.o  output/pjlib-arm-apple-darwin10/activesock.o  output/pjlib-arm-apple-darwin10/array.o  output/pjlib-arm-apple-darwin10/config.o  output/pjlib-arm-apple-darwin10/ctype.o  output/pjlib-arm-apple-darwin10/errno.o  output/pjlib-arm-apple-darwin10/except.o  output/pjlib-arm-apple-darwin10/fifobuf.o  output/pjlib-arm-apple-darwin10/guid.o  output/pjlib-arm-apple-darwin10/hash.o  output/pjlib-arm-apple-darwin10/ip_helper_generic.o  output/pjlib-arm-apple-darwin10/list.o  output/pjlib-arm-apple-darwin10/lock.o  output/pjlib-arm-apple-darwin10/log.o  output/pjlib-arm-apple-darwin10/os_time_common.o  output/pjlib-arm-apple-darwin10/os_info.o  output/pjlib-arm-apple-darwin10/pool.o  output/pjlib-arm-apple-darwin10/pool_buf.o  output/pjlib-arm-apple-darwin10/pool_caching.o  output/pjlib-arm-apple-darwin10/pool_dbg.o  output/pjlib-arm-apple-darwin10/rand.o  output/pjlib-arm-apple-darwin10/rbtree.o  output/pjlib-arm-apple-darwin10/sock_common.o  output/pjlib-arm-apple-darwin10/sock_qos_common.o  output/pjlib-arm-apple-darwin10/sock_qos_bsd.o  output/pjlib-arm-apple-darwin10/ssl_sock_common.o  output/pjlib-arm-apple-darwin10/ssl_sock_ossl.o  output/pjlib-arm-apple-darwin10/ssl_sock_dump.o  output/pjlib-arm-apple-darwin10/string.o  output/pjlib-arm-apple-darwin10/timer.o  output/pjlib-arm-apple-darwin10/types.o`
    `ranlib -static -o ../lib/libpj-arm-apple-darwin10.a output/pjlib-arm-apple-darwin10/ioqueue_select.o output/pjlib-arm-apple-darwin10/file_access_unistd.o output/pjlib-arm-apple-darwin10/file_io_ansi.o output/pjlib-arm-apple-darwin10/os_core_unix.o output/pjlib-arm-apple-darwin10/os_error_unix.o output/pjlib-arm-apple-darwin10/os_time_unix.o output/pjlib-arm-apple-darwin10/os_timestamp_posix.o output/pjlib-arm-apple-darwin10/os_info_iphone.o output/pjlib-arm-apple-darwin10/guid_simple.o output/pjlib-arm-apple-darwin10/os_core_darwin.o output/pjlib-arm-apple-darwin10/addr_resolv_sock.o output/pjlib-arm-apple-darwin10/log_writer_stdout.o output/pjlib-arm-apple-darwin10/os_timestamp_common.o output/pjlib-arm-apple-darwin10/pool_policy_malloc.o output/pjlib-arm-apple-darwin10/sock_bsd.o output/pjlib-arm-apple-darwin10/sock_select.o output/pjlib-arm-apple-darwin10/activesock.o output/pjlib-arm-apple-darwin10/array.o output/pjlib-arm-apple-darwin10/config.o output/pjlib-arm-apple-darwin10/ctype.o output/pjlib-arm-apple-darwin10/errno.o output/pjlib-arm-apple-darwin10/except.o output/pjlib-arm-apple-darwin10/fifobuf.o output/pjlib-arm-apple-darwin10/guid.o output/pjlib-arm-apple-darwin10/hash.o output/pjlib-arm-apple-darwin10/ip_helper_generic.o output/pjlib-arm-apple-darwin10/list.o output/pjlib-arm-apple-darwin10/lock.o output/pjlib-arm-apple-darwin10/log.o output/pjlib-arm-apple-darwin10/os_time_common.o output/pjlib-arm-apple-darwin10/os_info.o output/pjlib-arm-apple-darwin10/pool.o output/pjlib-arm-apple-darwin10/pool_buf.o output/pjlib-arm-apple-darwin10/pool_caching.o output/pjlib-arm-apple-darwin10/pool_dbg.o output/pjlib-arm-apple-darwin10/rand.o output/pjlib-arm-apple-darwin10/rbtree.o output/pjlib-arm-apple-darwin10/sock_common.o output/pjlib-arm-apple-darwin10/sock_qos_common.o output/pjlib-arm-apple-darwin10/sock_qos_bsd.o output/pjlib-arm-apple-darwin10/ssl_sock_common.o output/pjlib-arm-apple-darwin10/ssl_sock_ossl.o output/pjlib-arm-apple-darwin10/ssl_sock_dump.o output/pjlib-arm-apple-darwin10/string.o output/pjlib-arm-apple-darwin10/timer.o output/pjlib-arm-apple-darwin10/types.o`
`make -f /Users/RajaSekhar/Desktop/siphone/pjproject/build/rules.mak APP=TEST app=pjlib-test ../bin/pjlib-test-arm-apple-darwin10`
`if test ! -d ../bin; then mkdir -p ../bin; fi`
`/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/llvm-gcc -o ../bin/pjlib-test-arm-apple-darwin10 \`
`output/pjlib-test-arm-apple-darwin10/main.o  output/pjlib-test-arm-apple-darwin10/activesock.o  output/pjlib-test-arm-apple-darwin10/atomic.o  output/pjlib-test-arm-apple-darwin10/echo_clt.o  output/pjlib-test-arm-apple-darwin10/errno.o  output/pjlib-test-arm-apple-darwin10/exception.o  output/pjlib-test-arm-apple-darwin10/fifobuf.o  output/pjlib-test-arm-apple-darwin10/file.o  output/pjlib-test-arm-apple-darwin10/hash_test.o  output/pjlib-test-arm-apple-darwin10/ioq_perf.o  output/pjlib-test-arm-apple-darwin10/ioq_udp.o  output/pjlib-test-arm-apple-darwin10/ioq_unreg.o  output/pjlib-test-arm-apple-darwin10/ioq_tcp.o  output/pjlib-test-arm-apple-darwin10/list.o  output/pjlib-test-arm-apple-darwin10/mutex.o  output/pjlib-test-arm-apple-darwin10/os.o   output/pjlib-test-arm-apple-darwin10/pool.o  output/pjlib-test-arm-apple-darwin10/pool_perf.o  output/pjlib-test-arm-apple-darwin10/rand.o  output/pjlib-test-arm-apple-darwin10/rbtree.o  output/pjlib-test-arm-apple-darwin10/select.o  output/pjlib-test-arm-apple-darwin10/sleep.o  output/pjlib-test-arm-apple-darwin10/sock.o  output/pjlib-test-arm-apple-darwin10/sock_perf.o  output/pjlib-test-arm-apple-darwin10/ssl_sock.o  output/pjlib-test-arm-apple-darwin10/string.o  output/pjlib-test-arm-apple-darwin10/test.o  output/pjlib-test-arm-apple-darwin10/thread.o  output/pjlib-test-arm-apple-darwin10/timer.o  output/pjlib-test-arm-apple-darwin10/timestamp.o  output/pjlib-test-arm-apple-darwin10/udp_echo_srv_sync.o  output/pjlib-test-arm-apple-darwin10/udp_echo_srv_ioqueue.o  output/pjlib-test-arm-apple-darwin10/util.o -O2 -arch armv6 -isysroot /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.0.sdk -framework AudioToolbox -framework Foundation -lbz2 -lz -lpthread  -framework CoreAudio -framework CoreFoundation -framework AudioToolbox -framework CFNetwork -framework UIKit -framework AVFoundation -framework UIKit -framework CoreGraphics -framework QuartzCore -framework CoreVideo -framework CoreMedia  ../lib/libpj-arm-apple-darwin10.a  -O2 -arch armv6 -isysroot /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.0.sdk -framework AudioToolbox -framework Foundation -lbz2 -lz -lpthread  -framework CoreAudio -framework CoreFoundation -framework AudioToolbox -framework CFNetwork -framework UIKit -framework AVFoundation -framework UIKit -framework CoreGraphics -framework  QuartzCore -framework CoreVideo -framework CoreMedia`     
`arm-apple-darwin10-llvm-gcc-4.2: ../lib/libpj-arm-apple-darwin10.a: No such file or directory`
`make[2]: *** [../bin/pjlib-test-arm-apple-darwin10] Error 1`
`make[1]: *** [pjlib-test] Error 2`
`make: *** [all] Error 1`
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: in the pjlib/include/pj/config_site.h.  Added following code into it.

    #define PJ_CONFIG_IPHONE 1
    #include <pj/config_site_sample.h>

Now able to compile libraries but getting the error while linking in xcode-siphon code ,
Lexical Preprocessor issue fatal error: 'pjsua-lib/pjsua.h' file not found

Comment: linked the libraries in header search and lib search path recursively. Now getting the following error.

../pjproject-svn/pj/compat/setjmp.h:30:12: error: unknown type name 'jmp_buf'

Comment: error gone when follwing line is commented in that file


    #define PJ_HAS_SETJMP_H 1

Comment: The line `#define PJ_HAS_SETJMP_H 1` that needs to be commented out is in  **pjproject-2.1.0/pjlib/include/pj/compat/os_auto.h** line 63.

Comment: @RajaTSSekhar: I am facing the same issue. I am using **PJSIP version 2.5.5** and **XCode 8.2.1**. Please help me to resolved this issue.a

Answer (score 3):

pjsip has numerous headers that are duplicate names of core foundation headers. This can cause havoc if your source and search paths are not set up carefully.

Answer (score 0):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15601480/467588). I think basically you are including all actual pjsip headers into your project. This causes those conflict problems. It appears that the Header Search Paths settings is enough for the compiler to look for those headers.

So you don't need to comment that `#define PJ_HAS_SETJMP_H 1` line out. Just leave it like that.