# How do i use pjsip in my own iOS-project?

Tags: ios, libraries, pjsip

I have sucessfully downloaded the source code for pjsip and compiled it for iphone. I can run the iOS example project that comes with the release. The next step for me is to build my own project that uses the pjsip libraries, this i where i start having problems.

I have added the same libraries that the sample project uses to my project. I have also set the "Header Search Paths" under "Build Settings" to "${SOURCE_ROOT}" After that i try to include the pjsip library by typning:

```
#include <pjsua-lib/pjsua.h>
```

xcode gives me the error 'pjsua-lib/pjsua.h' file not found. Can anyone tell me what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to include the folders

```
path/to/pjsipprojectfolder/pjsip/include
path/to/pjsipprojectfolder/pjmedia/include
path/to/pjsipprojectfolder/pjnpath/include
path/to/pjsipprojectfolder/pjlib-util/include
path/to/pjsipprojectfolder/pjlib/include
```

to your "Header Search Paths" under "Build Settings".

Now the compiler can find all the *.h files

Comment: @joakimb how did you added Path? I am having the same issue. I am also following this tutorial.

Comment: Added all the paths even it is not working...Pls tell me what to do?